# Set array values from a JavaScript file using C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following syntax inside my JavaScript file:

```
var pageviews = [[1, 5+randNum()],
                [2, 10+randNum()], 
                [3, 15+randNum()], 
                [4, 20+randNum()],
                [5, 25+randNum()],
                [6, 30+randNum()],
                [7, 35+randNum()],
                [8, 40+randNum()],
                [9, 45+randNum()],
                [10, 50+randNum()],
                [11, 55+randNum()],
                [12, 60+randNum()],
                [13, 65+randNum()],
                [14, 70+randNum()],
                [15, 75+randNum()],
                [16, 80+randNum()],
                [17, 85+randNum()],
                [18, 90+randNum()],
                [19, 85+randNum()],
                [20, 80+randNum()],
                [21, 75+randNum()],
                [22, 80+randNum()],
                [23, 75+randNum()],
                [24, 70+randNum()],
                [25, 65+randNum()],
                [26, 75+randNum()],
                [27, 80+randNum()],
                [28, 85+randNum()],
                [29, 90+randNum()], 
                [30, 95+randNum()]];
```

where the format of one value is `[day of the month, total amount]`

Is there a way to set values from a List (ASP.NET)? I want to get the values coming from a database?

Comment: use JSON bult-in .NET libraries to transform data to and from.

Comment: you can use JSON and you can use Built-in Libraries or better you can use the Popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET  Json.NET http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: There are several ways to do this, primarily using json, but it would be great if you could be more specific about the exact technology you are using and how these values are used. For example, if you are binding these values to a control (e.g drop down ) then in ASP.NET MVC you can store these values in the view model and then, on your page, bind them to the target control. I believe we can help you more if you provide some more details.